# Replacement for STAF/STAX framework

Tags: java, testing, automation, continuous-integration

I was thinking of using STAF/STAX in one of my projects. I was wondering if there are any other frameworks, commonly used in industry that i can try before deciding?

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for different framework for testing Automation Tool/Framework

1. IBM Rational Robot
       you can download it from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/downloads/)

May be [this](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TestingFramework) resource will be useful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with STAF/STAX, but if you're looking for a continuous integration-server, I'd suggest taking a look at [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). We use it to build our server-projects, which contain multiple different Maven-projects (components forming the "server-stack" under the actual projects), that are built, unit/integration-tested and integrated automatically by a Hudson-instance monitoring the changes in our version control.